# Why is the input text not going away for my livewire modal form the is generated with alpine js?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm new to the world of livewire and alpine JS. I'm trying to write a livewire form in a modal. The form works fine but whenever I close the form the last text I entered into my into doesn't go away. I've had a look at the console when I press save or cancel I'm getting this error:

module.esm.js:1068 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i is not a function at module.esm.js:1068:28.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Here's the copy of the form in my modal.

```html
<div>
<div x-data="{ open: false }">

    <!-- Trigger button inside the modal -->
    <button @click="open = true" wire:click="clearModel" class="text-sm text-black font-medium p-2 hover:bg-gray-900 hover:text-white">Add More</button>
    
    <!-- Modal container -->
    <div x-show="open" 
            class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50"
            style="display:none">
        <!-- Modal background with a higher z-index -->
        <div class="modal-background fixed inset-0 bg-slate-50 opacity-50 z-40"></div>
        <!-- Modal content with a lower z-index -->
        <div class="modal-content bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-4 z-50">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <form wire:submit="createRequirement">
                @csrf
                <label for="name" class="block font-bold text-gray-800">Requirement Name</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model="name" class="text-black form-input mt-1 block w-full" placeholder="skills">
                <button x-on:click="open = false" type="submit">Add</button>
                <button x-on:click="open = false" type="button" class="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Cancel</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here's a copy of my livewire component:

```php
use Livewire\Component;
    
class SummaryTables extends Component
{
    public $work;
    public $name ='';
    public $type ='';
    public $showForm = false;
    
    
    public function render()
    {
    
    }
    
    public function createRequirement()
    {
        ModelA::create([
            'work_id' => $this->plan->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'type' => 'Additional'
            // Add other requirement properties here
        ]);
    
        $this->reset('name','type');
    
    }
    
    public function clearModel()
    {
        $this->name = '';
        $this->type = '';
    }
    
    public function deleteRequirement($id)
    {
        $requirement = ModelA::findOrFail($id);
        $requirement->delete();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue (assuming you're using Livewire 3): https://wirebox.app/b/y89qx

Comment: Also, calling `clearModel` is not necessary because your variables are already cleared with the `reset()`. Livewire will then return the new content to the client with your empty variables.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier thanks for having a look. I've set up Apline JS and Livewire on my laravel application using npm install for both of them. I read the documentation and I can see from your example it worked fine which is making me think it's a set-up issue?

Comment: If you're using Livewire 3, don't add AlpineJS to your project. It's already shipped with Livewire and will cause conflicts

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier thank you thank you thank you very much. After removing the Alpine JS I installed everything is working fine now!